# Is kumaran's email an offer or invitation to treat? Why

Tags: contract-law

Kumaran, an electrician, develops novel lampshades. In January 2016, he developed a new lampshade suitable for use with compact fluorescent lights.

**On 1 May 2016, he emailed Bobby and Chew, both wholesalers, to whom he had previously sold lampshades. In his email, he asked each of them whether he would be interested in becoming the sole distributor of his new lampshade.**

Is this an offer or an invitation to treat?

Comment: Nice story. What is your question? Whether or not Kumaran is bound to Bobby?

Comment: I would like to know whether the email to bobby and chew is an offer or merely an invitation to treat.   @mikeazo

Comment: 1: which email from kumaran?; 2: this is just an amendment to http://law.stackexchange.com/q/14055/4501

Comment: <On 1 May 2016, he emailed Bobby and Chew, both wholesalers, to whom he had previously sold lampshades. In his email, he asked each of them whether he would be interested in becoming the sole distributor of his new lampshade. >  is this as offer or invitation to treat

Answer (score 3):

It's not an offer. An offer must be sufficiently complete that it is able to be accepted and thereby form a contract. If the wholesalers were to write back "I accept" - what, precisely are the terms of the contract?

It is an invitation to treat in that is is "...an expression of willingness to negotiate."